# ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_CreatePrimary.c:135:Esys_CreatePrimary() Esys Finish ErrorCode (0x000009a2)

Tags: linux, openssl, tpm

**Question is based on TPM openssl Engine**

I have configured and make install everything as per the link
**tpm2-tss-engine, tpm2-tss, tpm2-tools**
for tpm2-tss when i make install i am getting
**warning messages warning: relinking 'src/tss2-tcti/libtss2-tcti-swtpm.la' ...etc**

I have configured tpm2-tss-engine openssl.conf.sample

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
tpm2tss = tpm2tss_section

[tpm2tss_section]
engine_id = tpm2tss
#dynamic_path = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1/libtpm2tss.so
default_algorithms = RSA
#,ECDSA
init = 1
SET_TCTI = device:/dev/tpmrm0
SET_OWNERAUTH = 123
#SET_PARENTAUTH = <password_of_parent_key>

[req]
distinguished_name = subject

[subject]
```

Next:
When i issue the command openssl engine -t -c tpm2tss i works
And i can create rsa key using command tpm2tss-genkey -a rsa rsa.tss
But when i issue command

Without sudo
openssl req -new -x509 -engine tpm2tss -key rsa.tss -keyform engine -out rsa.crt
It prompts some question i entered the next is below error i am getting but crt file not created

```
WARNING:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tcti-device.c:429:Tss2_Tcti_Device_Init() Failed to open default TCTI device file /dev/tpmrm0: Permission denied
WARNING:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tcti-device.c:429:Tss2_Tcti_Device_Init() Failed to open default TCTI device file /dev/tpm0: Permission denied
ERROR:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tcti-device.c:433:Tss2_Tcti_Device_Init() Could not open any default TCTI device file
WARNING:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tctildr.c:79:tcti_from_init() TCTI init for function 0x7f151cd626c9 failed with a000a
WARNING:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tctildr.c:109:tcti_from_info() Could not initialize TCTI named: tcti-device
ERROR:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tctildr-dl.c:154:tcti_from_file() Could not initialize TCTI file: device
ERROR:tcti:src/tss2-tcti/tctildr.c:416:Tss2_TctiLdr_Initialize_Ex() Failed to instantiate TCTI
139728687178176:error:8007306F:tpm2-tss-engine:esys_ctx_init:Some unknown error occured:src/tpm2-tss-engine-common.c:81:
139728687178176:error:8008206D:tpm2-tss-engine:rand_bytes:Unknown TPM error occured. Please check tpm2tss logs:src/tpm2-tss-engine-rand.c:58:
```

With sudo
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -engine tpm2tss -key rsa.tss -keyform engine -out rsa.crt
It prompts some question i entered the next is below error i am getting but crt file not created

```
WARNING:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_CreatePrimary.c:393:Esys_CreatePrimary_Finish() Received TPM Error
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_CreatePrimary.c:135:Esys_CreatePrimary() Esys Finish ErrorCode (0x000009a2)
139987063673280:error:80071097:tpm2-tss-engine:init_tpm_parent:Owner authorization failed:src/tpm2-tss-engine-common.c:508:
139987063673280:error:80072096:tpm2-tss-engine:init_tpm_key:Authorization failed:src/tpm2-tss-engine-common.c:564:
139987063673280:error:8007406F:tpm2-tss-engine:esys_ctx_free:Some unknown error occured:src/tpm2-tss-engine-common.c:106:
139987063673280:error:8008C096:tpm2-tss-engine:rsa_priv_enc:Authorization failed:src/tpm2-tss-engine-rsa.c:160:
139987063673280:error:8007406F:tpm2-tss-engine:esys_ctx_free:Some unknown error occured:src/tpm2-tss-engine-common.c:106:
139987063673280:error:0D0DC006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_sign_ctx:EVP lib:../crypto/asn1/a_sign.c:212:
```

**My system configuration:**
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

What should i do, is there any idea for this how can i overcome from this

Comment: I would focus here: `Failed to open default TCTI device file /dev/tpmrm0: Permission denied` First try running as `root`, and if that works, then figure out what the actual permissions should be and use udev to change them correctly.

Comment: Presuming you actually have TPM devices available, you should also check group permissions on `/dev/tpmrm0` - adding yourself to the `tss` group may fix the device permissions issue.

Comment: I have installed udev and configured .rule/tpm.. , I can generate key rsa.tss but can able to create certificate .crt using sudo openssl req -new -x509 -engine tpm2tss -key rsa.tss -keyform engine -out rsa.crt but gettong errors as above same.